# How to find torrent peers in python?

Tags: python, bittorrent

I'm looking to build a bittorrrent client in python. Here is my code to find peers. It only returns none. How do I fix it?

bencodepy is a simple BEncode library

```
import bencodepy
import hashlib
import btdht 
import binascii 
from time import sleep 
f = open("debian.torrent","rb") 
decoded = bencodepy.decode(f.read())

info = bencodepy.encode(dict(decoded.get(b"info"))) 
info_hash = hashlib.sha1(info).hexdigest() 
dht = btdht.DHT() 
dht.start() 
sleep(15) # wait for the DHT to build

while True: 
    print(dht.get_peers(info_hash.encode())) 
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get DHT peers if I use `binascii.a2b_hex()` to convert the infohash into a byte string.

e.g.

```py
import bencodepy
import hashlib
import btdht 
import binascii 
from time import sleep 
f = open("debian.torrent","rb") 
decoded = bencodepy.decode(f.read())

info = bencodepy.encode(dict(decoded.get(b"info"))) 
info_hash = hashlib.sha1(info).hexdigest() 
print(f"{info_hash=}")
dht = btdht.DHT() 
dht.start() 
sleep(15) # wait for the DHT to build

while True: 
    print(dht.get_peers(binascii.a2b_hex(info_hash)))
    sleep(1)
```

Testing notes: I used `debian-11.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso.torrent`, available [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/bt-cd/) to test this. After the 15-second bootstrapping period, it took an additional 5 seconds to find my first peer, and another second to find about 50 peers.